# Code chunks rendered in too large a font

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The font used to render code chunks (whoel paragraphs rather than in-line) is too large, and larger than on say SO. This makes it difficult to insert code chunks from languages such as R in Questions or Answers. Code chunks are then displayed with scrollbars. For example, a trivial bit of R code:

```
> colnames(model.matrix(Y ~ Pred1*Pred2*Pred3*Pred4*Pred5 -1, data = DF))
     [1] "Pred1"                         "Pred2"                        
     [3] "Pred3"                         "Pred4"                        
     [5] "Pred5"                         "Pred1:Pred2"                  
     [7] "Pred1:Pred3"                   "Pred2:Pred3"                  
     [9] "Pred1:Pred4"                   "Pred2:Pred4"                  
    [11] "Pred3:Pred4"                   "Pred1:Pred5"                  
    [13] "Pred2:Pred5"                   "Pred3:Pred5"                  
    [15] "Pred4:Pred5"                   "Pred1:Pred2:Pred3"            
    [17] "Pred1:Pred2:Pred4"             "Pred1:Pred3:Pred4"            
    [19] "Pred2:Pred3:Pred4"             "Pred1:Pred2:Pred5"            
    [21] "Pred1:Pred3:Pred5"             "Pred2:Pred3:Pred5"            
    [23] "Pred1:Pred4:Pred5"             "Pred2:Pred4:Pred5"            
    [25] "Pred3:Pred4:Pred5"             "Pred1:Pred2:Pred3:Pred4"      
    [27] "Pred1:Pred2:Pred3:Pred5"       "Pred1:Pred2:Pred4:Pred5"      
    [29] "Pred1:Pred3:Pred4:Pred5"       "Pred2:Pred3:Pred4:Pred5"      
    [31] "Pred1:Pred2:Pred3:Pred4:Pred5"
```

The font size on SO seems more useful in this respect, and the font doesn't need to bee that big for code anyway.

Comment: Looks fine to me, and exactly the same fonts as on StackOverflow. (I'm using Firefox 3.6.10 on Windows XP).

Comment: This could be a linux thing? I'm viewing both sites in Chromium 8.0.560.0(0) and FireFox 3.5.15 under Fedora 12. I have later versions of those apps running on my laptop and at home with the same difference in font sizes between SO and CV.

Comment: Seems no-one from the team is willing to check it :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I missed this request. I have reduced the code font size a bit. The change will be in the next deployment. (The change applies to both the parent site and Meta)

Comment: Thanks Jin. Much appreciated!

Comment: I experienced the same "disagreement"... Now it looks pretty fine under Safari 5.0.3 (os x 10.6)!